# Unable to convert dual fisheye image to equirectangular image using ffmpeg package

Tags: ffmpeg, fisheye, 360-degrees

I am trying to convert dual fisheye image captured in an insta360 camera to equirectangular format using the ffmpeg package but I am unable to get the correct result. I used the following code,

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf v360=dfisheye:equirect:ih_fov=360:iv_fov=360 output.jpg
```

the input image,[input_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIhvu.jpg)

the output image, [output_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vvHE.jpg)

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Bot horizontal and vertical Field Of View of the cameras can't be 360, they are by sure just a little more than 180, try this:

ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf v360=dfisheye:equirect:**ih_fov=190:iv_fov=190** output.jpg

Hint: add "yaw" parameter to move the camera right and left:

ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf v360=dfisheye:equirect:ih_fov=190:iv_fov=190:**yaw=90** output.jpg

[image: Examples]

[image: source dual fisheye]

[image: result equirectangular]

View result pasting here the equirectangular image: https://renderstuff.com/tools/360-panorama-web-viewer/

Comment: How to get gyro data to avoid unnecesary rotation?

Comment: try with an exif viewer

Comment: Anyway. Your solution will only work if images are placed horizontally, side by side. Otherwise, I am getting result similar to the one shown in question. In my case, images will be never aligned, it depends from camera rotation, as shown in my question: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/35572/merge-insta360-insv-files-into-360-video-with-ffmpeg-360vr-filter. Maybe it's possible to calculate angles grom gyro data and provide them to ffmpeg. But that won't be possible with movies, because camera rotation keeps changing.

Comment: if exif data contain orientation data, you can feed them to FFMPEG. If they are not, you can proceedby trial&error with a low-res images, changing yaw, pitch and roll until you get a good image.

Comment: They mus contain some kind of oreintation data, because Insta360 studio is able to detect correct orientation. You can event change camera orientation while recording video and it does not affect to final movie after conversion.